# iPhone - sending an image with Sharekit to Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to send a comment and an image to facebook. Everything's working fine except that if no user image exists (in the coredata/sqlite db) I would like to send a default image instead. Here's my code, with `example.png` being the default image and `initWithData:entity.userImage` being the image the user added with their iPhone. Maybe there's something wrong with my if else statement.

```
-(IBAction) fbButton {

    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/ae/artist/XXX"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take a look at %@", entity.name]];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];


    if (entity.image = nil) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example.png"];
            SHKItem *item2 = [SHKItem image:image title:nil];
            [SHKFacebook shareItem:item2];

    } else {


            UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:entity.userImage] autorelease];


            SHKItem *item2 = [SHKItem image:image title:nil];
            [SHKFacebook shareItem:item2];

    }       


    [SHK flushOfflineQueue];
```

}

The problem is that if there is no image in the database Sharekit gives a UIAlert saying that a file must be present in the upload. I was trying to get around this by always providing a default image in case the record in the database doesn't have one.

as always, thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE   `if (entity.image == nil)`
instead this  `if (entity.image = nil) {`

```
if (imageView.image == nil) {
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbicon.png"];
                SHKItem *item2 = [SHKItem image:imageView.image title:@"Hi"];
                [SHKFacebook shareItem:item2];
            }
            else {
            SHKItem *item1 = [SHKItem image:imageView.image title:@"Hi"];
            [SHKFacebook shareItem:item1];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = imageview.image
SHKItem *item;

item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Hi"];

[NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"SHKFacebook"]) 
    performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```