# Post drawing to Facebook friend

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on an application in which I use Facebook API.  In this application there are 2 Facebook friends.  The first friend will draw a design and post it on the second friend's Facebook wall. The second friend will then understand that drawing and reply to first friend.

In my code I have made a design but I don't have the knowledge of how to post it on friend's wall with my app invitation.

Here is the code for making the design:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    prelocation=lastLocation;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touchOb=[touches anyObject];

    prelocation=[touchOb locationInView:self];

    //Get value of selected button

    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *value= [defaults objectForKey:@"clickValue"];

    NSLog(@" value of flag is %@",value);


    if([value isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@" in Erasing");

        CGRect rect1=CGRectMake(prelocation.x,prelocation.y,4,4);

        UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];

        view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        [self addSubview:view1]; 
    }
    else
    {   
        if(inkIndicator.value>0.0)
        {
            NSLog(@" in drawing");

            CGRect rect1=CGRectMake(prelocation.x,prelocation.y,2,2);

            UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];

            view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

            [self addSubview:view1];

            counter++;

        } 
        if(counter==10)
        {
            inkIndicator.value--;
            counter=0;
        }
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touchOb=[touches anyObject];

    lastLocation=[touchOb locationInView:self];

    //    NSLog(@"in start slidr value is %f",drawController.inkIndicator.alpha);

    //Get value of selected button


    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *value= [defaults objectForKey:@"clickValue"];

    NSLog(@" value of flag is %@",value);


    if([value isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@" in Erasing");

        CGRect rect1=CGRectMake(prelocation.x,prelocation.y,4,4);

        UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];

        view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        [self addSubview:view1]; 
    }
    else
    {
        if(inkIndicator.value>0.0)
        {
            NSLog(@" in drawing");

            CGRect rect1=CGRectMake(prelocation.x,prelocation.y,2,2);

            UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];

            view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

            [self addSubview:view1];

            counter++;

            NSLog(@" slidr value is %f",inkIndicator.value);
        }

        if(counter==10)
        {
            inkIndicator.value--;
            counter=0;
        }

    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I made the drawing with the help of small rectangles. How can I post them?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a UIImage
The easiest way is to capture the UIView into a UIImage, please use the following code

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToCapture.bounds.size, viewToCapture.opaque, 0.0);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Then after you create a UIImage you will need to send it to facebook, please refer to the answer to this question [iPhone - sending an image with Sharekit to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977684/iphone-sending-an-image-with-sharekit-to-facebook)